# Highligh group of cells based on a condition - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I have the following table consisting of three rows, the outcome is to highlight all cell on a single row only if more than 8 following cells has a value 1.

For example in the first row, I have 6 consecutive cells with a value 1, but since that doesn't meet my criteria of 8 consecutive cells with value 1 it will not be highlighted. Row 2 has 8 consecutive cells (from G to N) so it gets highlighted. Row three has more than 8, so it highlights all cells until a blank row appears.

[image: Clic to see my example table]

On my data table, I will only have values of Blank or 1's. But since the number of rows and cells is big, doing manually would take a lot of time. Do you know of a formatting formula or maybe by doing coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to your sample, I would suggest you use the conditional format formula `=MIN(IF(A1:$U1<1,COLUMN(A:$U)),COLUMN($U3))-MAX(IF($A1:A1<1,COLUMN($A:A)),COLUMN($A1))>8`.

The MIN function and the MAX function respectively calculate the number of columns on the right and left of the cell that are closest to the cell and do not meet the requirements, and then compare these 2 values. If it is greater than "8", it returns "TRUE" .

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Emily. This works perfect, it is what I was looking for. -MG